# Neo4j - Kafka, How to connect these two?

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka

How to connect or load data from Kafka to neo4j. I saw Mazerunner, DocManager in Neo4j documentation to connect Neo4j with Spark and MongoDB. Is there any such kind of projects related to Kafka and neo4j.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this GitHub project. This is with Neo4j 2.2.3 KernelExtention.
Link: https://github.com/ducky427/neo-kafka
You may need to change the settings code for any 3.0.x version.

Another way, if you are using Neo4j Embedded version, you can simply integrate these through your custom API.
Do share, if you have found other ways to integrate.